# Validation failed for one or more entities. what to do to fix error after finding cause. how to display error in web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, entity-framework, validation, ef-code-first

I got a `validation failed for one or more entities` error and then I have applied following solution to look into details:

Added a line: `((System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException)$exception).EntityValidationErrors`

into watch window to see what is the main cause behind the error...

It explained me the error but it did not state any solution to fix it. Why the validation can't be performed or why error message can not be displayed on a web page near the text box?